# Specifying namespaces explicitly inside method definitions

Tags: c++, namespaces

Let's suppose I have a namespace `Foo` and I have declared a class `Bar` inside of it with a constructor inheriting a class `Base` with its constructor along with some other class `Baz` with a publicly accessible method `boo()`:

```
namespace Foo {
    class Baz {
    public:
        void boo();
    };
    class Base {
    public:
        Base();
    };
    class Bar: public Base {
    public:
        Bar();
    };
}
```

Now I want to define the `Bar` constructor in my implementation as follows:

```
Foo::Bar::Bar(): Foo::Base::Base() {
    Foo::Baz::boo();
}
```

It appears as though it's OK to write it down like this:

```
Foo::Bar::Bar(): Base() {
    Baz::boo();
}
```

Meaning that once I specify the namespace in `Foo::Bar::Bar()` explicitly, there is no need to specify it later in the definition of this method.

Does it work like that everywhere from the explicit mentioning of the namespace up to the end of the definition?

Comment: good practices are mainly opinion based, however you save some typing if you place also all the implementation insde `namespace Foo { .... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at your `Bar` constructor definition:

```
Foo::Bar::Bar(): Base() {
    Baz::boo();
}
```

Once the declaration-part of the constructor (`Foo:::Bar::Bar`) have been read by the compiler, it knows the scope and it's no longer needed.

A more interesting example would be e.g.

```
namespace Foo
{
    struct Baz {};

    struct Bar
    {
        Baz fun(Baz);
    };
}

Foo::Baz Foo::Bar::fun(Baz)
{
    // Irrelevant...
}
```

Now, for the definition of the structure itself, `Baz` doesn't need any namespace-qualifier since it's defined in the namespace and all the symbols of the namespace is available directly.

The definition of the function `fun` is a different. Because it's not defined inside the namespace, we need to fully qualify the `Baz` structure for the return type. And the same for the actual function-name. But then like before once that part is read and parsed by the compiler, it knows the scope and knows that the argument `Baz` is really `Foo::Baz`.

You can read more about name lookup [in this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup).

Comment: And even `auto Foo::Bar::fun(Baz) -> Baz {/*..*/}`.